# Navigation Pop-Up Behavior Not Working as Expected in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've been trying to clear the back stack completely by using the popUpTo() function as soon as the user navigates to the dashboard screen after authenticating, but when pressing the back button, I can still see the older destinations rather than exiting the app. Here is the code (this is a multi-module app):

```
@Composable
fun RootGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    isUserLoggedIn: Boolean
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        route = NirvanaAppScreen.Root.name,
        // show app logo screen first
        startDestination = NirvanaAppScreen.splashScreen.name
    ) {
  loginGraph(navController = navController,
            navigateToDashboardGraph = {
                navController.navigate(Dashboard_Graph_Route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
            }
        )
   }
}
```

I was expecting to exit the app upon pressing the back button after navigating to dashboard screen, but the back stack doesn't get cleared for some reason. What part of my code is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the 'popUpTo' setting, you must set the 'inclusive' property to true to clear all fragments up to a specific target. However, this adjustment needs to start a little earlier. For Example;

```
navController.navigate(Dashboard_Graph_Route) {
popUpTo(NirvanaAppScreen.Root.name) {
    inclusive = true
}
launchSingleTop = true }
```

Comment: It worked! It's really strange that the documentation does not mention this anywhere (I have looked into all the pages related to this topic). Thank you anyways!